# header columns validation in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

"|" delimited files should have below column headers

```
Activity
Activity+ ID
Description
Status
```

After upload, before start processing the file using SQLLDR, I make sure the uploaded file has exact number of headers, headers names are matching and in same order.

Code:

```
declare -i header=4
fields=( 
"Activity"
"Activity+ ID"
"Description"
"Status"
)

for i in "Test File.csv"; do
    read -r line < "$i" 

    oldIFS="$IFS"
    IFS=$'|'
    fldarray=( $line );
    IFS="$oldIFS"

    nfields=${#fldarray[@]}     
    if (( nfields < header ))
    then
    printf "error: only '%d' fields in file '%s'\nmissing:" "$nfields" "$i"
    else        
        for item1 in "${header[@]}"; do
          for item2 in "${fields[@]}"; do
           if [[ $item1 != $item2 ]]; then
            Array3+=("$item1")
           fi
         done
        done
        echo "not matching" ${Array3[@]}
        printf "\n\n"
    fi
done
```

Data:

```
Activity|Activity+ ID|Description|Status
Test|1234|First activity|Open
```

This is always printing that Activity+ column is missing, though it is present in the file. After I remove the "+" from header and file uploaded, it is working as expected.
How can I change the above code to validate column headers with "+".
I referred the answer from [bash to identify and verify file headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43456005/bash-to-identify-and-verify-file-headers) to build this solution

Comment: Please show the exact content of file the file.  "Should have below column headers", what if it does not?  Also check that your line endings are ok (dos2unix).

Comment: I just ran your code on my system, and "Activity+" is not reported as missing.  But I had to guess the format of the input file.  Please add so I can check again.

Comment: @Nic3500 updated question. Exact column name is "Activity+ ID", i executed this now again and saying "Activity+ ID" missing column header.

Comment: Can the headers show up in different order? The quick & dirty solution would be to compare line 1 with the fixed string `Activity|Activity+ ID|Description|Status`.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I cannot do that because i need to know which column header is not matching

Comment: Ahhh, perhaps edit your question to clarify "make sure the uploaded file has exact number of headers and headers names are matching" to say that you're interested in which one is missing.  Is a different ordering OK, or not? (again, an edit is better than a comment)

Comment: @JeffSchaller Updated the question and also I tried comparing 2 arrays in for loop do find the difference, but it is still not working

Comment: I don't see in the update whether it's OK for the fields to be in different orders -- will they always be `Activity|Activity+ ID|Description|Status` or can they be `Status|Activity|Activity+ ID|Description` (for example)?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes it has to be in same order and updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** still a bit confused as to what OP wants to do (eg, `header` is defined as an integer but later referenced as an array (`"${header[@]}"`))

Assumptions:

- print an error if the number of `|` delimited fields in the first row of the `.csv` file does not match the number of entries in the `fields[]` array
- header fields from the `.csv` file must be an exact match (spelling and order) as the entries in the `fields[]` array
- print the entries from the `fields[]` array that don't have an exact match with the `|` delimited fields from the first row of the `.csv` file

We'll keep the current `fields[]` array:

```
fields=("Activity" "Activity+ ID" "Description" "Status")
```

The pull the first line of the `.csv` file into the `headers[]` array:

```
IFS='|' read -r -a headers < test.csv      # read first line from test.csv, break on '|' delimiter, store in headers[] array
```

Giving us:

```
$ typeset -p fields headers
declare -a fields=([0]="Activity" [1]="Activity+ ID" [2]="Description" [3]="Status")
declare -a headers=([0]="Activity" [1]="Activity+ ID" [2]="Description" [3]="Status")
```

Now make some modifications to OP's `if/else/for/fi` code:

```
if [[ "${#fields[@]}" -ne "${#headers[@]}" ]]            # field count mismatch?
then
     echo "error: field count mismatch: expecting ${#fields[@]} / found ${#headers[@]}"
else
    Array3=()                                            # init array Array3[]

    for ((i=0;i<${#fields[@]};i++))                      # loop through indices of fields[] array
    do
        [[ "${fields[$i]}" != "${headers[$i]}" ]] && \   # if same position in both arrays is not a match then ...
        Array3+=("${fields[$i]}")                        # add fields[] entry to Array3[]
    done

    [[ "${#Array3[@]}" -ne 0 ]] && \                     # if Array3[] not empty then ...
    echo "not matching:" ${Array3[@]}                    # print list of fields to stdout
fi
```

For this particular case, where `${fields[@]}` and `${headers[@]}` are identical, no output is generated.

Other test cases:

**2nd field in headers[] is spelled differently**

```
declare -a fields=([0]="Activity" [1]="Activity+ ID" [2]="Description" [3]="Status")
declare -a headers=([0]="Activity" [1]="Activity+" [2]="Description" [3]="Status")

# the code generates:

not matching: Activity+ ID
```

**headers[] has 3 entries**

```
declare -a fields=([0]="Activity" [1]="Activity+ ID" [2]="Description" [3]="Status")
declare -a headers=([0]="Activity" [1]="Activity+ ID" [2]="Status")

# the code generates:

error: field count mismatch: expecting 4 / found 3
```

**headers[] has 4 entries but all differ from corresponding entry in fields[]**

```
declare -a fields=([0]="Activity" [1]="Activity+ ID" [2]="Description" [3]="Status")
declare -a headers=([0]="Activity+ ID" [1]="Description" [2]="Status" [3]="Activity")

# the code generates:

not matching: Activity Activity+ ID Description Status
```

From here OP should be able to tweak the code to provide the desired outputs and/or set some variables to use for follow-on conditional operations (eg, abort processing if either `echo` is triggered, disable follow-on processing if either `echo` is triggered, etc).

Comment: works perfectly. Thank you so much. For some reason "+" value is causing a problem in the if loop, so i replace it with word "PLUS" then compare and in the final mismatch return value i replace it back to "+".

Comment: one last help, last header value is saying not matching though it is matching. may be it is ending with carriage return or some special char. So before if "[[ `"${fields[$i]}" != "${headers[$i]}" ]]" i added these 2 lines `${fields[$i]}=`echo ${fields[$i]} | xargs echo -n`; ${headers[$i]}=`echo ${headers[$i]} | xargs echo -n` but still not working

Comment: assuming the visible characters are identical ... try running `head -1 file | od -c` to see if there are any non-printing characters in the line (eg, `\r`); also run `typeset -p <array_name>` and carefully review the contents of each array entry (eg, does the last entry show an ending of `\r`?); if you are seeing the character `\r` the easiest solution would be to first run `dos2unix <filename>` (to remove `\r` characters) and then proceed with the rest of the code; if you're unable to address the issue at that point I'd suggest opening a new question to address this new issue

Comment: Thanks, there was \r and \n at the end, replaced and it works as expected.